# Automatically run autoformat file on file save in MS Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, autoformatting

In MS Visual Studio 2012 I can run file autoformat manually (press Ctrl+K+D by default). But I want automatically run autoformat on file save. How I can do this, if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found plugin for VS 2013 [Format on Save](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56). It's works good for me, but I had to install VS 2013 for use this plugin.